# What do each of the relics do in the Twisted League?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

A big part of the Twisted League is the relic system. You earn points to gain permanent upgrades to your character (for instance, I now have 0 stamina drain and 4x hp regen). It looks like there are a few tiers of relics, but their effects are currently hidden to me. What do each of the relics do in the Twisted League?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Relics can be found on [the Wiki](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Twisted_League#Relics):

#### First Selection (no points):

- **Abyssal Accumulator**:  You save 85% of your ammunition and runes.
- **Endless Endurance**: Your run energy drain-rate is reduced to 0 and your hitpoints restore 4 times as quickly.
- **Dark Altar Devotion**: Bones dropped by creatures are automatically buried and award 4 times the experience. Ensouled heads now drop two at a time. Your prayer drains at 1/2 the rate.

#### Selection 2 (400 points):

- **Hardcore Harvester**: You receive 3 times the normal amount of resources from Mining, Fishing, Woodcutting, Harvesting Herb, Blast Mining and Farming Contracts. These additional resources do not grant bonus XP. You receive 3 times as many Molch Pearls from Aerial Fishing. Farming cycles occur every 1 minute instead of every 5 minutes.
- **Arcane Courier**: All Wintertodt Crates and resources gathered from Mining, Fishing, Woodcutting, Harvesting Crops and Blast Mining are automatically sent to the bank.
- **Unnatural Selection**: When receiving Slayer tasks and Farming contracts, you can now choose what you are assigned.

#### Selection 3 (1200 points):

- **Eye of the Artisan**: You receive 2x XP in Smithing, Cooking, Firemaking, Herblore, Fletching, Crafting and Construction. This stacks with any existing XP multipliers.
- **Gift of the Gatherer**: You receive 2x XP in Mining, Fishing, Woodcutting, Hunter, Thieving, Farming and Runecraft. This stacks with any existing XP multipliers.
- **Way of the Warrior**: You receive 2x XP in Attack, Strength, Defence, Hitpoints, Magic, Ranged and Prayer. This stacks with any existing XP multipliers.

#### Selection 4 (2500 points):

- **Spirit of Dinh**: You take 0 damage from the cold, braziers breaking and falling snow at the Wintertodt. The Wintertodt's cold aura will no longer interrupt actions which you are doing. Wintertodt crates now award 3x more loot.
- **Konar's Blessing**: You gain 10% increased Accuracy and Damage with Melee, Magic and Ranged when fighting creatures. This boost increases to 30% when fighting creatures which are assigned to you as a slayer task.
- **Treasure Seeker**: Creatures which drop clues now drop them at a 1/10 rate.
  Clue geodes, clue nests and clue bottles are now found 10x more often from all skilling activities from which they can be found. All un-started clues are stackable. All clues have the lowest number of steps for their tier.

#### Selection 5 (5000 points):

- **Xeric's Focus**: You will now attack slightly more often with all attack styles!
  When attacking with melee, ranged or magic, the delay between your attacks is reduced by 0.6 seconds. This delay will never be less than 0.6 seconds.
  Special attacks with instant attacks such as the Granite Maul or Dragon Throwing axes are unaffected..
- **Xeric's Resilience**: You take 50% less damage from all creatures.
  Your prayer restores at a rate of 1 point every 3.6 seconds.
- **Xeric's Wisdom**: You gain 2x XP in every skill. This stacks with any existing XP multipliers.

This has been confirmed as correct by [Jmod Husky on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JagexHusky/status/1194961647053488129).